# Joi validation and pattern

Tags: node.js, validation, joi

Hello I am trying to make a composite Joi validation but I fail.

What I am trying to validate is the following object:

```
    {
      content: {
        dynamicKeyName: {
          title: '1',
          link: 'ggdf',
          order: 1,
        },
        dynamicKeyName2: {
          title: 'tttt',
          link: 'bbbb',
          order: 2,
        },
        .
        .
        .
      }
    }
```

I am trying to create a validation rule that will have many sub objects like the dynamicKeyName object without knowing the exact key name but to have similar value object.

I have written the following Joi rules:

```
const subSchema = Joi.object().required().keys({
  title: Joi.string().required(),
  link: Joi.string().required(),
  order: Joi.number().integer().required(),
});

const schema = Joi.object().keys({
  content: Joi.object().pattern(/^[\w\d]+$/, subSchema),
  .
  .
  .
});
```

However when I run the validation I get an error of: "additional property dynamicKeyName should NOT have additional properties"

Answer (score 1):

So I tried the schema and example you have posted above and it works fine.

May be its some other key that is causing the problem.

[image]

Try pasting entire schema and data you are trying to test.